# Ruby Dir['**/*'] limit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, glob

Is it possible to set a limit on Dir.each method? I would like to retrieve only last 10 files (ordered by create date).

Example:

```
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, '*.json'), 10].each do |f|
  puts f
end
```

Thx.

Comment: Does Ruby even let you retrieve the creation date?

Comment: No it doesn't. Linux doesn't store the creation time for files, only last access, last modification, and last inode-change time, so it was probably a lowest-common denominator based decision. Mac OS allows it to be accessed when sorting `ls` and via `mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate -raw`, but it's part of the file's meta-data, not the directory information. Windows seems to support it, but putting in a function that only worked well on one platform isn't good for a language.

Comment: @Greg: Actually, there's tons of stuff in Ruby that only works on POSIX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of those times when it might be more efficient to ask the underlying OS to do the heavy lifting, especially if you're combing through a lot of files:

```
%x[ls -rU *.json | tail -10].split("\n")
```

On Mac OS that will open a shell, sort all '*.json' files by their creation date in reverse order, returning the last ten. The names will be returned in a string so `split` will break them into an Array at the line-ends.

The `ls` and `tail` commands are really fast and doing their work in compiled C code, avoiding the loops we'd have to do in Ruby to filter things out.

The downside to this is it's OS dependent. Windows can get at creation data but the commands are different. Linux doesn't store file creation date.

Answer (score 2):

#### The last 10 files by ctime...

---

```
Dir['*'].map { |e| [File.ctime(e), e] }.sort.map { |a| a[1] }[-10..-1]
```

The second `#map{}` just strips off the ctime objects so if you don't mind working directly with the array of `[ctime, fname]` you can leave it off.

Comment: `ctime` returns the time the file's inode was most recently changed, not the time the file was created.

Comment: Good point, and I did think about that. But I usually provide a portable, within-the-API version, at least on the first pass. That gets an answer up there that will be generally useful to other site visitors. If the OP should respond that he really did need exactly creation time and that mod time wasn't good enough, well, then it's back-to-the-drawing-board time for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try each_with_index
http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003141

```
Dir[...].each_with_index do |f, i|
  break if i == 10
  puts f
end
```

And create a script to use the .atime
http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M002547

to create a conventional naming system based on date.

Comment: this doesn't address the ordering, or the fact that he wants the last ten files.

Comment: `atime` returns the time that the file was last accessed, not the time the file was created.

Comment: This doesn't do any sorting either.